# Can't access magento website after installation

Tags: magento2, vps

I've been trying to install Magento2 on a VPS (Ubuntu 20.04), using this guide:
https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/install-magento-2-4-6-on-ubuntu-22-04/

First time, I managed to install it completely and I could access the website frontend and backend.
P.S. I had to add the IP address and the domain name in the /etc/hosts file, cause I wanted to check the website in localhost first.

Everything was good, after a week the website suddenly stopped working, and gave me no errors. just a long loading time and after 5 minutes, the browser gave me the error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I double checked everything, and couldn't find the problem. So I just re-installed everything.
By the way two step auth is not mentioned in the guide above, so I disabled it myself.

After a successful installation, I still cannot access the website.

I know the explanation is not enough, but I don't know what other details should I provide.

I would really appreciate some help!

Thank you!

Things that I tried:
1- Re-installed magento using Apache, no result.
2- Changed the network.host to 0.0.0.0, and back to 192.168.0.1: no result.
3- Tried other installation guides like: https://cloudkul.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-4-on-ubuntu/ , no result again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT." message, the server is not responding to your connection request. I would recommend that you focus on the web server/Apache first.

**1. Confirm that Apache or NGINX is running**

To check that Apache is actually running on the server, run the following command:

```
systemctl status apache2
```

If Apache is not running then start it with

```
systemctl start apache2
```

If you are running NGINX you can check if it is running

```
systemctl status nginx
```

and if it is not run it with

```
systemctl start nginx
```

**2. Check Web Server Access/Error Logs for information**

*For Apache* - Check Apache error logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log to see if any messages there. It also may be helpful to check the access log to see if traffic is even hitting the server at /var/log/apache/access.log

*For NGINX* - Check NGINX error logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log to see if any error messages there. It also may be helpful to check the access log to see if traffic is even hitting the server at /var/log/nginx/access.log

**3. Review port or firewall settings**

If there was not any record of your attempt to visit the site in the access.log then it's highly possible that the issue is firewall related. Make sure that you have added port 80 and 443 to the firewall with the following commands

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

Also, depending on where the VPS is hosted at there may be a hosting level control panel where these ports are opened as well.

**4. Check what is listening on those ports**

You can also check what is listening on those two ports as it's possible that something else is using the ports. You can do that using netstat

```
sudo netstat -tuln | grep 80
sudo netstat -tuln | grep 443
```